# How to plot line graph in java/jsp using database values?

Tags: jsp, graph

How to plot graph in jsp from the database

In database two int values  **'x'** and **'y'**

```
(x,y)=(1,3),(2,4),(3,4)
```

How to plot these values from the database?

Note

Not from directly plotting values its only from database 
Without using **applet,JSON,or any Servlet**..Please help me in detail

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Dojo Toolkit](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/charting.html#charting-basics) for this.

Only JavaScript is required. Ajax is possible but not required.

Comment: Please give me a sample code for that..its not taken from database..its applied only direct values..

Comment: Load your values into a variable and set them into the dojo code. Btw: this is a basic usage and you should take some JSP/JavaScript tutorials if you are not common with it.